App service Staging slot not showing updated changes
I created a staging deployment slot in production environment App-Service with the idea that once everything looks okay in staging environment, I'll swap it with production. I have successfully deployed the new changes to staging slot from Visual Studio multiple times since yesterday but still the new changes are not reflected when I browse staging url. They are same as production.
When I deploy the same changes to a different app service which we have for development environment, the changes are reflected fine but not on staging environment.
What am I missing here? I know there is no special recipe needed to do it. Its same as publishing to production slot after finding the connection details from "Publish profiles".

Please share more details about the issue.If possible share the code repo.

Check your environment in the configuration file.

I am able to deploy the changes to staging slot without any issues.

In Visual Studio to deploy new changes to any slot, you need to select the new Profile.


and make sure you have selected the correct slot.


If you still have issues in deploying the new changes, check the below workaround.


we have for development environment, the changes are reflected fine but not on staging environment.


As you are able to deploy the changes to development slot, modify the required changes (as you want them in staging) in VS and deploy them to development slot.

Create a new slot with name staging.




Swap the development slot to newly created staging slot.



Now you will be able to see the changes (of development) in staging.



I checked with Microsoft support team and found that in some cases we need to restart our staging slot after deploying the changes and that's what I did which made it work.
